# Force material button to wrap text in two lines

Tags: android-layout, material-design

I have a Material Button with a text that I'd like not to ellipsize, but instead to wrap up to the second line so the whole button width could be set to `wrap_content`.
Unfortunately the UI wraps content preferring to keep the text as a single line.

So far I've tried to set following properties:

```
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:lines="2"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ellipsize="none"
```

Is there a way to avoid scrutiny calculating the word I'd like to add a text break manually in the code and force the layout to use the second line as well?

Comment: can you share button code too?

Comment: There isn't much code apart from setting the text value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newline character `\n` in string resource file,

```
<string name="sample">This\nis a sample</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this as a backup due to hackiness with translations. Was looking for some general Android solution.